# Reading & displaying value in Datetimepicker

Tags: c#, datetimepicker, custom-properties

I am writing a date in xml file & then reading a date from xml file to display.
I have used `Datetimepicker` which has customFormat= `MM/dd/yyyy`. & it sets `<date>02/29/2001</date>` in xmlfile.

while reading if value is `"02/02/2001"`it reads & shows it perfectly in datetimepicker

but if value is `"02/22/2001"`. **edited**:

it throws an exception.
**String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

Comment: `02/29`is only a valid date when the year is a leap year - 2001 clearly is not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the cultureinfo of your application to expect the date in a MM/dd/yyyy format? It seems like it is expecting dd/MM/yyyy, that's why 02/02/2001 works, I suspect 28/02/2001 would work as well.

Edit: Hang on, 2001 was not a leap year, 29/02/2001 will never be a valid date!

Edit: added sample

```
// C#
// Put the using statements at the beginning of the code module
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
// Put the following code before InitializeComponent()
// Sets the culture to English (US)
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
// Sets the UI culture to English (US)
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

from here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b28bx3bh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
more info in the link to the class in the comments

Comment: is this windows forms or a web application?

Answer (score 2):

The string `"02/29/2001"` actually doesn't form a valid date, since February 2001 only has 28 days and your string reads as **February 29th, 2001**, same as like **January 32nd, 2001**.

Answer (score 1):

```
string val = "10/10/2010";
dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(val);
```